# Creating own OAuth 2.0 server for smartphone apps - DotNertOpenAuth example issue

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, server, smartphone

I know this is a wide question, but I found only old stuff. I need to create my own OAuth 2.0 server. I've a special need: I have to make it work for smartphone apps. I work in C# and I wish my server will be done in this language.

I've read the specifications **"The OAuth 2.0 Authorization framework"** and **"The OAuth 2.0 Authorization framework: bearer token usage"**. The theory is clear, but I don't have any ideas for start my work.

For example, there are a lot of libs, which one is the best for  work with smartphone apps? I think these libs I've found have a lack on docs and samples.

Do you know where can I find a stepByStep tutorial or a working sample? I see a lot of fog around this argument.

Where can a newbie of this field start? After I read the specifications, what have I to do?

I'm stuck here and I'm asking your help! :)

UPDATE:

I'm looking the OAuthAuthorizationServer example from DotNetOpenOauth lib. I'm trying first to use it as I've dowloaded it, using the *sampleconsumer* id. But, I get an error: **"No OpenID endpoint found. - Sequence contains no matching element"**

In this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var rp = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        var u = new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Action("Authenticate"));
        var request = rp.CreateRequest(model.UserSuppliedIdentifier, Realm.AutoDetect, u);
        if (request != null) {
            if (returnUrl != null) {
                request.AddCallbackArguments("returnUrl", returnUrl);
            }

            return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
        } else {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The identifier you supplied is not recognized as a valid OpenID Identifier.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

the error is the var request = rp.CreateRequest... code line. Why?

Comment: The DotnetOpenAuth should have a working Oauth2 server among their examples.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I saw them, but nothing mobile-oriented. Can you suggest me one of these samples?

Comment: Does "mobile" make a difference here? I thought you need a c# server and the mobile app is the client.

Comment: @WiktorZychla is there one or more stepByStep tutorial? I'm watching the sample "OAuthAuthorizationServer".. but with a tutorial it'd be easier...

Comment: Nope, at least never seen one.

Comment: @WiktorZychla can you look my update?

Comment: Why are you trying to use an openid client against oauth2 server? That won't work. Try a minimal client setup I described here http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simple-oauth2-federated-authentication.html